# Blazored Local storage works only on first page render

Tags: local-storage, blazor, blazor-server-side

i have a method that i use to store user information on browser as below:

```
protected async Task AddToStorage(string key, string value)
{
   await localStorageService.SetItemAsync(key, value);
}
```

And here is how i inject the storage

```
 [Inject]
Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService localStorageService { get; set; }
```

thhe AddToStorage method gets called here after retrieving user info:

```
 protected async Task LoginMethod()
{
    try
    {
        authResult = await AuthenticationService.Login(new Models.Dtos.Requests.UserLoginRequest()
        {
            Email = Email,
            Password = Password
        });
        Token = authResult.Token;
        await AddToStorage("UserToken", Token);
        navigationManager.NavigateTo("/");

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```

But i doesn't add nothing to the browser local storage and after some tests i have seen that it works only inside on "OnAfterRenderASync" Method.

Comment: When do you call the LoginMethod?

Comment: `catch (Exception) {}` is very much an anti-pattern, it just hides errors.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Solved by changing from an async task to an async void

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Majorsoft.Blazor.Extensions.BrowserStorage/). It should work multiple times... Check the [docs](https://github.com/majorimi/blazor-components/blob/master/.github/docs/BrowserStorage.md) and [demo](https://blazorextensions.z6.web.core.windows.net/browserstorage) for more details.

**Very important Note**: WASM is not able to access HTML DOM or APIs (like Storage API) directly. So all of those **extensions were implemented by using [JsInterop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0)**. Blazor supports many [hosting models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-5.0). You can run it as **WASM SPA** application or **Server hosted** and rendered app with SignalR. For a WASM app `IJSRuntime` service can be injected and used at any point in the code execution even `OnInitialized()` etc. **But with Server side Blazor `IJSRuntime` cannot be used/accessed at any point *only after component was rendered!***

So if you have Blazor server project try to call 3rd party "JsInterop-ing" services after your component was already rendered. **This will be one common caveat for ALL extensions which using `IJSRuntime` service in ANY Blazor server app.**